# f2py external function always returns zero

Tags: python, callback, f2py

I need to make a python binding of a fortran90 code that takes a callback function as one of its inputs. I tried to follow the examples from the scipy webpage and created a helloworld file `helloworld.f90`, as follows:

```
SUBROUTINE helloworld(fun,a,b)
    external fun
    real*8, intent(in) :: a
    real*8, intent(out) :: b
    print*, 'Hellow world'
    print*, a
    b = fun(a)
    print*, b
END
```

I compile this with `f2py -c -m hello helloworld.f90`. The compilation works without error, but then, the python code doesn't work as expected: the function calls from python always return 0 (!?):

```
In [1]: import hello
In [2]: def fun(x): return x**2
In [3]: hello.helloworld(fun,2.)
Hellow world
  2.0000000000000000     
  0.0000000000000000     
Out[3]: 0.0
```

Does someone understand why `fun(2.)` is evaluated to `0` within fortran? Do I have a problem with my compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...
It seems that fortran casts the python float 2. to a 0. because of the required 8-bytes precision (why?). Anyway, changing `real*8` to `real` in the above code solved the problem.

Comment: Though not sure if this is a correct approach (for f2py), adding "real*8 fun" in the helloworld() routine seems to work on my computer...